# string.Format - timeSinceLevelLoad in 12:34 SS:MS

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine

I wish to format the timeSinceLevelLoad into a format of 00:00 so the player can see how many seconds and milliseconds they have been playing.

I am trying to do this by using string.Format and saving to my timeText variable, shown below.

```
void Update () {
    timeText.text = string.Format("{0:00}", Time.timeSinceLevelLoad);
}
```

Currently, I only get 00: counting up in seconds but have tried "{0:00}:{0:.00}" and some other variations.

Does anyone know of a way to do this cleanly in one line?

Comment: What type is `timeSinceLevelLoad`?  `TimeSpan`? `int` in terms of seconds/milliseconds/...?

Comment: I am just under the assumption that it is Time. I have seen TimeSpan mentioned but this was to format. When I just use {0}, it counts up in seconds and milliseconds

Comment: @madreflection it’s a float of seconds. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-timeSinceLevelLoad.html

Comment: So @MitchFeaver needs to do some basic math to get that in terms of minutes and seconds.

Comment: @madreflection, I dont want it in minutes and seconds. I want it formatted in 00:00 which reflect seconds and milliseconds

Comment: There are 1000 milliseconds in a second so you'll probably need `00:000` format. Unless you only want to display in tens of milliseconds

Comment: You're confusing things as the colon character : delineates between the parameter number and the format specifier.  Do you really need the : character instead of the standard . character between the seconds and milliseconds?

Comment: Hi @Mick, thanks for the reply. Yeah, I would just like to understand the best way to go about it. I always think time should be separated with :, which is the reason i want to use it

Comment: @MitchFeaver I have given you an answer but what you're doing is not standard.  For most english speaking people on this planet the : character usually separates minutes and seconds, not seconds and millisecs.  Most people would use the decimal point for that.

Comment: @MitchFeaver ... Which is the reason why I don't believe the string.Format method can do what you're asking for out of the box

Comment: I see your point, I understand. Thank you for the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
void Update () {
    timeText.text = string
        .Format("{0:00.00}", Time.timeSinceLevelLoad)
        .Replace(
            CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator, 
            ":");
}
```

**EDIT:** As stated in the comment on the question.  The desired format the questioner is after is non-standard.  No culture uses the : character to separate seconds and millisecs.  This character is more commonly used to separate minutes and seconds or hours and minutes. As such you need to use the replace function to replace the standard decimal separator with the non-standard separator.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you! I did not know there was a way to such a thing, so I'm glad I've learnt this!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Custom TimeSpan format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-timespan-format-strings) like this:

```
TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Time.timeSinceLevelLoad).ToString(@"%s\.ff");
```